# Create React App open browser using Ngrok URL

Tags: create-react-app, ngrok

When I run my CRA app locally using `react-scripts start` it opens a browser window automatically populated with `http://localhost:3000`.

This is great, however I am using ngrok and I want to make the browser open with my ngrok domain.

I understand there is a HOST environment variable which can be set, but this is not what I'm after.
Setting this HOST env variable causes CRA to run locally on this domain however I still want to run my local app on localhost (ngrok tunnels from your localhost).

I can see there's a BROWSER_ARGS variable, but I can't find any documentation on what kind of ARGS I can provide to it.  Maybe it's there?